# Django inlines for manyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `Profile` model that has OneToOne relationship with `User` model.
I also have a `Group` model that has `users` field as ManyToMany to `User`.

I am trying to achieve a simple thing in Django Admin: being able to create a group with some new users and allowing to fill out some of the profile fields for those new users.

I tried a couple of things

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Group.users.through
    inlines = [ ProfileInline ]


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('users',)
```

This is not working for me. I only see dropdown fields for user in my group admin and if I try to add a user the form does not have any profile fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Django admin inlines are only available if model has foreign key to other model. For you setup you have to find other solution related to your models relation.